# If look up returning multiple values in multiple cells

Tags: excel, formula

I am working on a budget and need some help with looking up a value and returning multiple text values (categories).

Basically transactions are exported via a customers bank. This has names dates etc. I am then trying to add a category at the end, for example, rent, bills, food. However some have subcategories. Food for example might be food core, or food junk.

I can populate one cell with the below formula pretty easy but not sure how to do two. The second category needs to be one box across but ideally in the same formula as I have thousands of lines

This is the code for the category 1,

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NEWWORLD", F2,1)),"FOOD")[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is incomplete. Kindly share which column is which, where is it taking the data from, what are the criteria for the formula, etc.

Comment: I can not see any "NEWWORLD" in any of the cells in both photos.

Comment: You should make a mastertable with gets the Description, Category 1, and Category 2. This mastertable would be kind of a database to clasify each description. Then, in your budget data, in the columns Category 1 and Category 2, use a VLKOOKUP function to search for the right value in your master table.